# Vaadin: How to make a validator accept numbers and one decimal only

Tags: java, regex, validation, vaadin

I'm trying to validate a textfield to it's only numbers and one decimal, but the decimal keeps causing the validator to go off:

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.addValidator(new RegexpValidator("^\\d+$", facilityId.getCaption() + "Only numbers and one decimal allowed."));
```

So I got the numbers to work, but how do I tell the validator that the "." is okay?

**Note:** Add-Ons are not an option.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work

```
/^\d+\.\d$|^\d+$/
```

Breakdown

`^` - start of line

`\d+` - One or more digit

`\.` - Escaping a period otherwise it will match any character

`\d$` - It ends with one digit after the decimal

`|` - Or

`^\d+$` - It has any number of digits without a decimal

Comment: I don't know vaadmin, but "?" would be a better solution and I believe it should know that also. 
^\d+(\.\d)?$

Comment: "invalid escape sequence"

Comment: tf.addValidator(new RegexpValidator("/^\d+\.\d$|^\d+$/", facilityId.getCaption() + " contains invalid characters."));

Gives me compile error "invalid escape sequence."

Comment: I don't know vaadmin, but I do know this is valid regex, because I tried it out on rubular.com.

Comment: "Valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \'' \' \\"

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes in the regexp string: `"^\\d+\\.\\d$|^\\d+$"` (here also remove the leading and trailing slash) or `"^\\d+(\\.\\d)?$"`

Comment: No you don't. You only need to escape backslashes by themselves. Or is this different than normal regex?

Comment: @RichardHamilton it's in Java and the expression is a String which means that backslashes have a special meaning, hence they need escaping themselves

Comment: @Null sorry, I forgot to add the @ in my previous comment so you may have missed a notification. When you have the chance please try escaping the backslashed as suggested above