# Vaadin TextBox: Numbers and decimal only.

Tags: vaadin

How do I get a textbox to give me an error if anything other than numbers and/or decimals are submitted?

Comment: What's different here than in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054129/vaadin-how-to-make-a-validator-accept-numbers-and-one-decimal-only)

Comment: This one has a real answer.

Comment: I'm glad you finally got what you were looking for. Nonetheless, the other one had an answer as well. If you follow my suggestion to escape the backslashes and remove the slashes, the answer works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a validator to the text field.

```
textField.addValidator(new Validator());
```

There is not a validator that checks if the value is a number or not in Vaadin, so you need to create a custom one:

```
private class MyValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(Object value)
            throws InvalidValueException {
        if (!(value instanceof Integer &&
                (value instanceof Double)) {
            throw new InvalidValueException("The value is not a number");
        }     
    }
}
```

Now you can add your custom validator to your field:

```
textField.addValidator(new MyValidator());
```

More info about validators [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.fields.html#components.fields.validation).

Answer (score 0):

```
private class MyValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(Object value) throws InvalidValueException {
         try {
              // new Integer(text);
                new Double(value.toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              throw new InvalidValueException("The value is not a number");
            }
    }
}
```